# How do I generate a set of n-tuples containing integral solutions to a linear equation provided certain constraints?

Tags: equation-solving, integral-equations, diophantine-equations

Let $m,k,p$  be fixed positive integers. I want to create a table of k-tuples $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k)$ comprised of solutions in positive integers to the equation below:

$$x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_k=m\quad\text{where }1\leq{}x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k\leq{}p$$

For example, if I set $m=16,k=3$,  and $p=6$. How can I make mathematica generate the set (table) of integer triples $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ such that $$x_1+x_2+x_3=16$$ where $1\leq{}x_1,x_2,x_3\leq{}6$.

Also, how would I seperately generate a table of positive integral triples $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ for which $$x_1+x_2+x_3\geq{}16 \quad \text{and } 1\leq{}x_1,x_2,x_3\leq{}6.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to read Documentation on functions [**Solve**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html) and [**Reduce**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reduce.html) and tutorial [**Solving Equations**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SolvingEquations.html). Look through this forum, I bet this is a duplicate question. There is also a guide: [**Diophantine Equations**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/DiophantineEquations.html).

```
{x1, x2, x3} /. 
 Solve[x1 + x2 + x3 == 16 && 1 <= x1 <= 6 && 1 <= x2 <= 6 && 
   1 <= x3 <= 6, {x1, x2, x3}, Integers]
```

> {{4, 6, 6}, {5, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 5}, {6, 4, 6}, {6, 5, 5}, {6, 6, 4}}

or alternatively

```
Reduce[x1 + x2 + x3 == 16 && 1 <= x1 <= 6 && 1 <= x2 <= 6 && 
  1 <= x3 <= 6, {x1, x2, x3}, Integers]
```

> (x1 == 4 && x2 == 6 && x3 == 6) || (x1 == 5 && x2 == 5 && 
>         x3 == 6) || (x1 == 5 && x2 == 6 && x3 == 5) || (x1 == 6 && 
>         x2 == 4 && x3 == 6) || (x1 == 6 && x2 == 5 && 
>         x3 == 5) || (x1 == 6 && x2 == 6 && x3 == 4)

Your 2nd question would be

```
{x1, x2, x3} /. 
 Solve[x1 + x2 + x3 >= 16 && 1 <= x1 <= 6 && 1 <= x2 <= 6 && 
   1 <= x3 <= 6, {x1, x2, x3}, Integers]
```

> {{4, 6, 6}, {5, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 5}, {5, 6, 6}, {6, 4, 6}, {6, 5, 5}, {6,
>         5, 6}, {6, 6, 4}, {6, 6, 5}, {6, 6, 6}}

Comment: Thanks for the code and references.

Comment: I don't know why but when I try to upvote your answer it gives me a -1 instead.

Comment: @EdwinMontufar Strange... you just have to click "upper" arrow for up-vote. Not sure if you experiencing a bug or clicking on a wrong thing. I hope I won't go negative 25K suddenly ;)

Comment: I'm definitely clicking that upper arrow =)

Comment: @EdwinMontufar you got it now, a +1 from you, thanks. I think that -1 is from someone else.

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me that for your first stated problem there is a much better method than `Solve` or `Reduce`:

```
{m, k, p} = {16, 3, 6};
IntegerPartitions[m, {k}, Range@p]
```

> ```
> {{6, 6, 4}, {6, 5, 5}}
> ```

If you want all permutations just use `Permutations`:

```
Join @@ Permutations /@ %
```

> ```
> {{6, 6, 4}, {6, 4, 6}, {4, 6, 6}, {6, 5, 5}, {5, 6, 5}, {5, 5, 6}}
> ```

For your second stated problem I believe this will be more efficient than `Solve` or `Reduce`:

```
Join @@ Table[IntegerPartitions[x, {k}, Range@p], {x, m, k*p}]
```

> ```
> {{6, 6, 4}, {6, 5, 5}, {6, 6, 5}, {6, 6, 6}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, don't forget about one of @Artes' favourite functions: `FrobeniusSolve`. The `Pick` statements select solutions with positive integers less than or equal to `p`.

```
kTuples[m_Integer, k_Integer, p_Integer] :=
   Block[{s = FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1, k], m]},
         s = Pick[s, UnitStep[Apply[Sequence, Table[p - s[[All, i]], {i, k}]]], 1];
         Pick[s, Map[FreeQ[#, 0] &, s]]
   ]
```

For your second question generating solutions greater than or equal to `m`:

```
kTuples2[min_Integer, k_Integer, p_Integer] :=
   Block[{s},
      Flatten[Table[
         s = FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1, k], m];
         s = Pick[s, UnitStep[Apply[Sequence, Table[p - s[[All, i]], {i, k}]]], 1];
         Pick[s, Map[FreeQ[#, 0] &, s]],
         {m, min, k*p}], 1]
   ]
```

The method becomes inefficient as `m`, `k`, and `p` increase because valid solutions must be selected from a possibly very large number of solutions returned by `FrobeniusSolve`.