# How many combinations of certain variables add up to at least n?

Tags: combinatorics

I have a set of numbers, let's say:
a=16
b=19
c=19
d=31
e=5
f=... etc.

How to create a simple function that shows how many combinations of the letters add up to at least the number n?

I have no clue what Mathematica Functions I should use to get started. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As a starting point, you could use `Tuple` to generate all combinations of letters of a given length; however some combinaison would be counted twice (e.g. $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$).

Comment: "At least"??  So you're interested in collections that might give a *higher* number too?  That unbounds your search.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Yes; at least indeed... but the size of the list is not unlimited...

Comment: So you DO want to allow *higher* numbers!  OK.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22397/how-do-i-generate-a-set-of-n-tuples-containing-integral-solutions-to-a-linear-eq

Comment: Something like this? `vals = {16, 19, 19, 31, 5};
min = 55;
expr = Times @@ (1 + x^vals);
Total[Drop[CoefficientList[expr, x], UpTo[min]]]

11`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

n=80

number of subsets

```
Length@Select[Total /@ Subsets[{13, 15, 19, 19, 23, 31}], # >= 80 &]
```

and if you want to see the selected subsets type

```
Select[Subsets[{13, 15, 19, 19, 23, 31}], Total[#] >= 80 &]
```

Comment: The question states "at least", so you should use $>$ (not $<$).  But I think the poser is mistaken in what he wants.

Comment: you are right! fixed

Comment: Great! This is almost what I need! Now, how do I visualize the lists that actually fall within the right category? And doesn't this solution also allow for duplicates?

Comment: ListPlot[DeleteDuplicates[
  Select[Subsets[{13, 15, 19, 19, 23, 31}], Total[#] >= 80 &]]]

Comment: @Jenny_mathy This is the endresult: Length@Select[Subsets[{31, 9, 19, 14, 19, 19, 6, 16, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2}], 
  Total[#] > 75&] It's the amount of possible coalitions after the Dutch elections tonight.

Comment: hehehehe...nice!

Answer (score 0):

First create a list of your allowable component integers:

```
myset = {1, 2, 3, 5, 20};
```

Then:

```
Length[Select[IntegerPartitions[20], ContainsOnly[myset]]]
```

(* 
92 
*)

`IntegerPartitions` gives a list of all the says you can add integers to give the candidate number.  Select from all those possible lists the ones that contain only the elements in your allowable component integers using `ContainsOnly` (version 10).  Then count (`Length`) that list.

If you must, you can kludge a function using set operations to select lists whose union with myset is myset.

Comment: ContainsOnly? I don't have that function...?

Comment: @David G. Stork You can directly use `IntegerPartitions[20, All, {1, 2, 3, 5, 20}] // Length`, instead of using `Select`.

Comment: @AnjanKumar:  Ah yes... I didn't know that `IntegerPartitions` had that option.  Thanks.